# Cómo importar correctamente modulos en python?

Tags: python, python-import

Al incluir desde el archivo main.py el modulo `from modules.interface import *` me genera este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/denso/Documents/ProgressControl/main.py", line 1, in <module>
 from modules.interface import *
 File "/home/denso/Documents/ProgressControl/modules/interface.py", line 2, in <module>
 from fullClases import *
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fullClases'
```

La estructura de mi proyecto es esta:

```
1. ProgressControl 
     1. modules
         1. fullClases.py
         2. interface.py
         3. jsonFiles.py
         4. __init__.py
     2. json
     3. main.py
```

El archivo `interface.py` importa correctamente al ejecutarlo el modulo `from fullClases import *`, cuál es la razón de este error?

Comment: Hola denso, bienvenido a [es.so]. En `interface.py` debes importar `fullClases` mediante `from modules.fullClases import *` o mediante `from .fullClases import *`. En la pregunta marcada como duplicado se explica porqué no funciona `from fullClases import *`, el import se resuelve en base a `main.py`. si aún así tienes alguna duda comenta. Por cierto te recomiendo seguir las convenciones de estilo para nombrar módulos, se usa minúsculas y _ como separador, CamelCase se reserva solo para el  nombre de las clases. Un saludo.

Comment: Lo ha solucionado gracias, la cuestión es que al hacer eso ahora no puedo compilar por separado el archivo interface.py, pero supongo que ya no es problema ello

Comment: En realidad si lo es, al importar así se asume que el punto de entrada de tu paquete es main.py y los imports están pensados para resolverse en base a ello. Si quieres ejecutar interface como principal para hacer algún test siempre puedes cambiar el import temporalmente por ejemplo. Hay más posibilidades como modificar sys.path pero en un proyecto bien estructurando generalmente esto ni es necesario ni buena práctica.